# Donation website security get rid of fraudsters

Tags: security

It sounds stupid but I want to get rid of fraudsters. I am trying to build a donation/charity website. People can raise donations from this. I am almost done but the main concern is how to get rid of fraudsters.

I want no fraud cases on my site. Right now I have these options:

- Register with official email id.
- Phone number verification (During registration)
- Website URL of respective charity/donation (During registration)

Can you advise something more?

Comment: I am not sure this is correct platform to ask this kind of question or not. Please do not down vote it.  Thanks

Comment: This is a complex problem, definitely too broad for Stack Overflow I'm afraid.

Comment: The question isn't very specific. What sort of fraud are you worried about? People pledging money but not paying? People giving other user's email addresses? Are you collecting credit card numbers? Are you worried about government regulations?

Comment: I am worried about people pledging money but not paying/not using on main clause. Yes, i will collect credit card numbers of doner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In e-commerce systems, enabling 3-D Secure at a payment gateway level can help.

It is offered by Visa as Verified by Visa and Mastercard call it MasterCard SecureCode. Other than that JCB International offer it as J/Secure and American Express offer it as American Express SafeKey.

In The UK [SagePay offer this service](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/3d-secure-explained), [as do Barclaycard](http://www.barclaycard.co.uk/business/existing-customers/internet-authentication) in [their web payment solutions](http://www.barclaycard.co.uk/business/accepting-payments/website-payments/website-payment-solutions).

Comment: You might want to provide some more information about what '3-D Secure' means, or at minimum provide a link to where more information can be found.

Comment: Added some background. :)